# How to evaluate tables/filters in Dax Studio

Tags: powerbi, dax, daxstudio

I am wondering is it possible to see in Dax Studio (or other editor) which values are used to filter measure (evaluate expresion that returns table)?
What I mean by that is I create a measure for example:

```
last 3 value = 
VAR DATES = DATESINPERIOD(calendar[date],LASTDATE(calendar[date]), -3,MONTH)
RETURN CALCULATE([sum value], DATES)
```

Now I would like to evalaute this expresion:

```
DATESINPERIOD(calendar[date],LASTDATE(calendar[date]), -3,MONTH)
```

in dax studio to see what values it produces that are later used in filtering.
I have searched for syntax that would allow it but I have failed. This example measure from above is easy, but I have one thats complicated and having the abillity to see its intermediate steps would help a lot.
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You can create another measure with the expression and check the values, did you try this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `EVALUATE` to return table expressions.

```
EVALUATE
DATESINPERIOD ( 'calendar'[date], LASTDATE ( 'calendar'[date] ), -3, MONTH )
```

See the documentation for more examples:

https://daxstudio.org/tutorials/writing-dax-queries/